# Can avocado tree grow in pot?

Tags: houseplants, fruit-trees, avocado

I recently planted a regular avocado seed on a 4" pot and it's growing nicely, but I know it will continue growing and growing.

Since it's a regular avocado bought at a supermarket, can can these grow in a pot (even if it's a big pot)? Will it produce fruit being in a pot?

I live in the Caribbean.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in principle you can keep any tree in a pot, it is also known as bonsai. You'll have to prune the roots and branches into proportion to keep it small enough for the pot. There is a lot of information on the web about how to get a tree into bonsai. Bonsai is a very long process and you need a lot of patience. I don't think you will get fruit from it by the way, so if you want avocados for consumption it would be better to plant it in full ground (I guess the West-Indies will have a good climate for avocados?).